# Ember router naming conventions

Tags: ember.js

I have a need for deep nesting some routes in ember, I have something like this.

```
  this.resource('wizards', {
    path: '/wizards'
  }, function() {
    this.resource('wizards.google', {
      path: '/google'
    }, function() {
      this.resource('wizards.google.register', {
        path: '/register'
      }, function() {
          this.route('step1');
          this.route('step2');
          this.route('step3');
          this.route('summary');
      });
    });
  });
```

What I was expecting was as structure like this:

```
url        /wizards/google/register/step1
route name wizards.google.register.step1
route      Wizards.Google.Register.Step1Route
Controller Wizards.Google.Register.Step1Controller
template   wizards/google/register/step1
```

but I got this:

```
url        /wizards/google/register/step1 //as expected
route name wizards.google.register.step1 //as expected
route      WizardsGoogle.Register.Step1Route
Controller WizardsGoogle.Register.Step1Controller
template   wizards/google.register.step1
```

What I don't get is when does ember stop using capitalization (WizardsGoogle) and start using namespaces (WizardsGoogle.Register). The seemingly inconsistency confuses me. I would have expected either of them.

Comment: Found this discussion http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/routers-nested-resource-implementation-is-extremely-limiting/927

Comment: This is a really interesting issue, especially since the ember docs seem to suggest that it should work exactly as you expected.  All I can find (through searching/testing) is that it apparently only works 1 level deep... though there's no logical reason why this should be the case.  Here's hoping someone can give you a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same things with deep nested resources. Although I didn't know how this happens, what I can tell is that you can always use CapitalizedNestedRoute without namespace, and Ember can recognize it. Although in Ember Inspector it displays "WizardsGoogle.Register.Step1Route".

In your example I defined such route:

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('wizards', function() {
    this.resource('wizards.google', function() {
      this.resource('wizards.google.register', function() {
        this.route('step1');
        this.route('step2');
        this.route('step3');
      });
    });
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    // Transition to step1 route
    this.transitionTo('wizards.google.register.step1');
  }
});

App.WizardsGoogleRegisterStep1Route = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // You can see this alert when you enter index page.
    alert('a');
  }
});
```

In this example the app will transition to WizardsGoogleRegisterStep1Route with no problem. And if you use container to find route like this:

```
App.__container__.lookup('route:wizards.google.register.step1').constructor
```

It will also display `App.WizardsGoogleRegisterStep1Route`. It's the same as Ember Guide describes. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources  And Ember Guide doesn't introduce namespace route.

So I think it's better to according to what Ember Guide suggests (always use CapitalizedNestedRoute). And in my opinion it's easier to define `CapitalizedNestedRoute` than `nested.namespace.route`.

Finally, if you really want to use namespace route/controller/template, you can have a look at [Ember.DefaultResolver](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-application/lib/system/resolver.js#L230). Check the API to learn how to extend it so container can lookup modules by your own rules.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies more. Will see if extending the resolver is worth it or if I'll just stick to the super long names. :) Still surprised they went with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Routes are "namespaced" inside resources. And resources uses what you call capitalization, where they sort of define a namespace (for routes to use).

So this set of routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('old');
    this.route('edit');
    this.route('whatever');
  });
});
```

Would result in routes with the following name:

```
PostsRoute
PostsNewRoute
PostsOldRoute
PostsEditRoute
PostsWhateverRoute
```

Whereas, the following set of routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('photos');
    this.resource('comments');
    this.resource('likes');
    this.resource('teets');
  });
});
```

Would result in route with the following names:

```
PostsRoute
PhotosRoute
CommentsRoute
LikesRoute
TeetsRoute
```

Also note, that resources within resources don't get "namespaced" to the "parent" resource, so you'll always ever have the form:

```
{CapitalizedResourceName}Route // for resources
{CapitalizedParentResourceName}{RouteName}Route // for routes
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Well this I understand, as it is quite simple examples. Ember uses Capital character each time it "namespaces" a route under a resource. I also understand that the resources nested like you say is "globalized", so not `PostsPhotos`. But why does `wizards.google.register` turn into `WizardsGoogle.Register` and not `WizardsGoogleRegister` or `Wizards.Google.Register`.